# How to setup an AWS Athena query with multiple regex replacements?

Tags: regex, amazon-athena, presto

I have been trying to make an AWS Athena query and got enough work done to get my data. However, my data needs to identify some patterns and change it in an uniform way in order to group those "similars". So I'm trying to make a regex_replacement, but how can i do multiple replacements to a same column in the same column?

Here's my query:

```
with q as (SELECT r.key,
   r.otherid,
   r.complexString,
   minute(date_trunc('minute', from_iso8601_timestamp(r.time) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York')) AS minute,
   hour(from_iso8601_timestamp(r.time) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AS hour,
   day(from_iso8601_timestamp(r.time) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') AS day
FROM requests0918 t
JOIN requests0918 t1 ON t.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.msg = 'response_written' AND t1.code = '200'
and t.otherid is not null
and t.key is not null
and t.path is not null
limit 10)
Select q.key, q.otherid, REGEXP_REPLACE(q.complexString, '\/accounts\/[0-9]+\/balances', '/accounts/.../balances' ) as path, q.minute, q.hour, q.day from q
```

So I'm successfully changing this strings to that ones, but I need to set more patterns and to replace under the same column name. So I'm looking on how to do it. I could add more layers of `with q as {Query}` to add more rules, but that sounds pretty wrong.

Comment: I might not be following exactly what you want to do, but you can nest function calls. eg. `REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(q.complexString, ':', 'colon'), ';', 'semicolon'))` would end up replacing both `:` and `;` with their names.